# F# : Writing a function that builds a list of tuples recursively, a syntax error

Tags: list, syntax, recursion, f#, tuples

I'm trying to write a recursive function that return a List < int * int>, but I'm having some trouble with the syntax.

The function should return an empty list when the recursione ends, otherwise a tuple (int * int) merged with a List returned by a recursive call to itself:

```
let rec foobar () : List<int * int> =
    if (recursionIsEnded) then
        []
    else 
        foobar () :: (10, 10) // this is wrong
        // (10,10) works, but I need to concatenate it with the elements returned by foobar recursive call
```

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I'll try to give more details . 
Actually my function is a bit more complicated. I'm iterating through a 2d array and build a list of tuples with the array index elements that satisfy a certain condition. Actually that's my code:

```
let rec GetSameColorNeighs(grid : Option<Ball> [,], row : int , col : int, color : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color) : List<int * int> =
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > MaxLineNumber - 1 || col > BallsPerLine - 1) then
        []
    else
        let ball = grid.[row,col]
        match ball with 
            |Some(ball) -> 

                if (!ball.visited = false || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) then
                    [row , col]
                else
                     ball.visited := true
                     (row,col) ::GetSameColorNeighs(grid, row + 1, col + 1, color) ::  GetSameColorNeighs(grid, row - 1, col - 1, color) 

            |None  -> []
```

So here's 2 more question :):

1. How modify the following row in order to make it compile?

   ```
   (row,col) ::GetSameColorNeighs(grid, row + 1, col + 1, color) ::  GetSameColorNeighs(grid, row - 1, col - 1, color)
   ```
2. Is there any better way to do that?

I don't care about the list's elements order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an inner function with an accumulator is probably the easiest way to do it (as a bonus it's tail recursive).

```
let foobar() =
  let rec foobar acc =
    if (recursionIsEnded) then
        List.rev acc
    else 
        foobar ((10, 10)::acc)
  foobar []
```

Based on your update, I'd prefer a mutable solution. Something like

```
let GetSameColorNeighs(grid : Option<Ball> [,], row : int , col : int, color : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color) : List<int * int> =
    let results = ResizeArray()
    let rec loop (row, col) =
      if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > MaxLineNumber - 1 || col > BallsPerLine - 1) then ()
      else
          let ball = grid.[row,col]
          match ball with 
              |Some(ball) -> 

                  if (!ball.visited = false || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) then
                      [row , col] //doesn't compile, not sure what to do here
                  else
                       ball.visited := true
                       results.Add(row, col)
                       loop(row + 1, col + 1) 
                       loop(row - 1, col - 1)

              |None  -> ()
    loop(row, col)
    results |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: I need a clarification. What if in the else branch I need to concatenate the result of more call to foobar? (like with GetSameColorNeighs in my edited example) What's the right syntax using the accumulator? And how can I modify your code is foobar has some parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel's solution looks good to me, but you don't need to use mutable state (`ResizeArray`). Instead, you can write the `loop` function as a sequence expression that generates results using `yield` and makes recursive calls using `yield!`:

```
let GetSameColorNeighs (grid:Option<Ball>[,], row, col, color:Color) =
  let rec loop (row, col) = seq {
    if not (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > MaxLineNumber - 1 
                    || col > BallsPerLine - 1) then
        let ball = grid.[row,col]
        match ball with 
        | Some(ball) -> 
          if (!ball.visited = false || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) then
            // Not sure what you want here - yield items using 'yield'?
            // [row , col] 
          else
            ball.visited := true
            yield row, col                 // Add single item to results
            yield! loop(row + 1, col + 1)  // Add all generated to results
            yield! loop(row - 1, col - 1)  //        -- || --
        | None  -> () }
  loop(row, col) |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: @Heisenbug Another nice feature of sequence expressions that you can yield things from a `for` loop (instead of iterating using recursion). However, I'm not sure if that would be useful in this case (depends on how you're processing the 2D array).

Comment: Actually I'm building a list of adiacent balls with the same color, starting from a given element of the array. Once build the list, I'll return a copy of the array without the element indexed in the list (since they are Option<>).

Comment: any particular reason you're not using Some(ball) when (!ball.visited = false || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) ->...? instead of the match and then if?

Comment: @Heisenbug it was mostly a question to Tomas, who must said to be rather experience :) and I'd like to know if he had a reason for choosing the if over the when construct.

Comment: @RuneFS - Not really, no reason. I just took the original code from Daniel and I did only minimum changes. Specifying the condition in `when` sounds perfectly fine to me (as long as the condition isn't too complex to make it hard to read).

Answer (score 1):

Since foobar returns a list you either have to append the lists or concat and then reverse

`(foobar())@(10,10)` however I'd usually do

it the other way around

```
   (10,10)::(foobar()))
```

and then reverse when you return. the above have a problem with tail recursion so to tweek that you end up with something like:

```
let foobar () : List<int * int> =
  let rec inner acc =
    if (recursionIsEnded) then
        list.Rev acc
    else 
        inner ((10, 10)::acc)
  inner []
```

reversing in the end should usually result in fewer operations than if you append a list to a list

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a simpler function, I hope it helps illustrate the point as your recurse through two lists to build tuples. This function takes two lists as input in the form ([],[]), and pairs each element together as a tuple in a new list.

```
let rec pairlists twolists = 
  match twolists  with
    | ([],[]) -> []
    | (x::xs, y::ys) -> 
            (x,y)::pairlists(xs,ys)
;;
```

Given two lists of the same length (If they aren't the same length you'll get an error), each recursion will pair the first two elements into a tuple as (x,y). The syntax:

```
(x,y)::pairlists(xs,ys)
```

Is really just saying "Build a tuple with our current elements (x,y), then proceed building tuples with the rest of our lists (xs,ys).

Run:

```
pairlists ([1;2;3], 1;2;3])
```

And you'll get the output:

```
[(1,1);(2,2);(3;3)]
```