# F# : Writing a function that builds a list of tuples recursively and change a mutable variable

Tags: recursion, f#, closures, mutable

This question is related to this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8423571/587884).

I followed Tomas's suggestion using this piece code, and all works fine:

```
let GetSameColorNeighs (grid:Option<Ball>[,], row, col, color:Color) =
  let rec loop (row, col) = seq {
    if not (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > MaxLineNumber - 1 
                    || col > BallsPerLine - 1) then
        let ball = grid.[row,col]
        match ball with 
        | Some(ball) -> 
          if (!ball.visited = false || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) then
            // Not sure what you want here - yield items using 'yield'?
            // [row , col] 
          else
            ball.visited := true
            yield row, col                 // Add single item to results
            yield! loop(row + 1, col + 1)  // Add all generated to results
            yield! loop(row - 1, col - 1)  //        -- || --
        | None  -> () }
  loop(row, col) |> Seq.toList
```

The code above iterate through an array 2d of "balls" and return a list of index of adjacent balls with the same color.

Now I have to modify the function in way that it returns also a boolean indicating if at least one ball of the list satisfy a certain condition. I changed the code this way but seems that I can't assign a mutable value inside that code:

```
let GetSameColorNeighs (grid:Option<Ball>[,], row, col, color:Color)  : List<int * int> * bool =
    let mutable b : bool = false
    let rec loop (row, col) = seq {
        if not (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > MaxLineNumber - 1 
                        || col > BallsPerLine - 1) then
            let ball = grid.[row,col]
            match ball with 
            | Some(ball) -> 
              if (ball.visited = true || not <| ball.color.Equals(color)) then
                ()
              else
                //HERE's THE PROBLEM
                if (ball_satisfy_a_certain_condition) then
                      b <- true
                ball.visited := true
                yield row, col                 // Add single item to results
                yield! loop(row + 1, col + 1)  // Add all generated to results
                yield! loop(row - 1, col - 1)  //        -- || --
            | None  -> () }
      loop(row, col) |> Seq.toList, b
```

It seems that a mutable variable can't be acquired by a closure (I don't know what it means).

So I have 2 questions:

1. why is the above assignment to a mutable variable wrong?
2. How should I refactor my code to achieve this goal?

Comment: change to "let b = ref false"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you have to use `ref` variables instead of mutable variables.

While mutable variables are allocated on the stack, `ref` variables are heap-based. After each time your `loop` function is invoked, mutable values are wiped out when `ref` values are still there. Therefore, only `ref` values are valid to return in `GetSameColorNeighs`.

This question has been asked many times here. See [The mutable variable 'i' is used in an invalid way.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480582/the-mutable-variable-i-is-used-in-an-invalid-way) and [this blog post](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/on-lambdas-capture-and-mutability/) for more in-depth discussion.

Comment: +1 thanks for the links..I'll read that carefully. BTW, the problem is that I'm using a third party f# module that redefine := operator. So when I try to do 'b := false ' I get an error. Do you know how can I redefine again ':=' operator in order to use it normally locally to my function?

Comment: The easiest way is using `b.contents <- false` instead of `b:=false`. You can redefine `:=` as mentioned in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data#Ref_cells but it will override the current `:=` operator everywhere, which you may not want.